# Python using BitString module to parse Image EXIF data

Tags: python, parsing, exif, bitstring, bitstream

I've been trying to parse Tiff and Jpeg image EXIF data using the BitStream module and just can't get it all going. Has anyone had better luck using it? If so, could you point me towards or can you share any example snippets?

I've spent a long time looking at and testing existing Python EXIF modules and so far all of them seem to be incomplete and unable to fully parse current EXIF image data.

I also looked at the Perl based EXIFTool which is a very complete tool, but when called from a Python shell call is 10x slower than calling native Python code to do the same.

This BitStream module really seems like it is the Python tool to use to parse binary data with.

Yet right now the learning curve has been steep.

The biggest problem I am running up against is all the EXIF Image Spec doc's just are not matching up to what I am seeing as I parse an image using BitStream.

It feels like I am getting closer here, but could use a little advice or code snippets from some others who have spent time parsing image file EXIF headers using BitStream and Python to get this back on track.

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried and we will help you identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks for asking, but right now I've spent enough time trying to get this idea going. I can now see why so many EXIF projects get abandoned. Dealing with internal binary meta/exif data is a real mess. For anyone reading this at a latter date save yourself some time and check out [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/). It appears to be the best answer at doing this.